# Thread-safe Dictionary.Add

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary, thread-safety

Is `Dictionary.Add()` thread safe when you only insert?

I've got a code that insert keys from multiple-threads, do I still need locking around Dictionary.Add()

I got this exception while adding a new key:

```
Exception Source:    mscorlib
Exception Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Exception Message:   Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Exception Target Site: Insert
```

Although it's quite rare. I know that `Dictionary` is not thread-safe although I thought that only calling `.Add` wouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Dictionary is not thread-safe **at all**, regardless of whether you only add to it or not - there are a few internal structures to it that need to be kept in sync (especially when the internal hashbuckets get resized).

You either have to implement your own locking around any operation on it, or if you're in .Net 4.0 you can use the new ConcurrentDictionary - which is absolutely fantastic - and which is totally thread-safe.

### Another option (update)

That said - there is another technique you can use - but it'll require a bit of tweaking depending upon the kind of data you're inserting into your dictionary, and whether all your keys are guaranteed unique:

Give each thread it's own private dictionary that it inserts into.

When each thread finishes, collate all the dictionaries together and merge them into a bigger one; how you handle duplicate keys is up to you.  For example, if you're caching lists of items by a key, then you can simply merge each same-keyed list into one and put it in the master dictionary.

### Official answer re: performance (after you accepted)

So as your comments say, you need an idea of the best method (lock or merge) for performance etc.  I can't tell you what this will be; ultimately it will need to be benchmarked.   I'll see if I can offer some guidance, though :)

Firstly - if you have any idea how many items your Dictionar(y/ies) will ultimately need, use the `(int)` constructor to minimize resizing.

The merge operation is likely to be best; since none of the threads will be interfering with each other.  Unless the process involved when two objects share the same key is particularly lengthy; in which case forcing it all to happen on a single thread at the end of the operation might end up zeroing all the performance gains by parallelizing the first stage!

Equally, there's potentially memory concerns there since you will effectively be cloning the dictionary, so if the final result is large enough you could end up consuming lots of resources; granted, though - they will be released.

If it's the case that a decision needs to be made the thread-level when a key is already present, then you will need a lock(){} construct.

Over a dictionary, this typically takes the following shape:

```
readonly object locker = new object();
Dictionary<string, IFoo> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IFoo>();

void threadfunc()
{
  while(work_to_do)
  {
    //get the object outside the lock
    //be optimistic - expect to add; and handle the clash as a 
    //special case
    IFoo nextObj = GetNextObject(); //let's say that an IFoo has a .Name
    IFoo existing = null;
    lock(locker)
    {
      //TryGetValue is a god-send for this kind of stuff
      if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(nextObj.Name, out existing))
        dictionary[nextObject.Name] = nextObj;
      else
        MergeOperation(existing, nextObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Now if that `MergeOperation` is *really* slow; then you might consider releasing the lock, creating a cloned object that represents the merge of the existing and the new object, then re-acquiring the lock.  However - you need a reliable way of checking that the state of the existing object hasn't changed between the first lock and the second (a version number is useful for this).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Any idea about the overhead cost of locking for all operations (insert/key lookup - 20~ threads) Is it really minimal or something that we need to be careful about?

Comment: well - it will depend how long over which the operations are going on; and whether there really are no reads occurring.  if it's the case that you have 20 threads thrashing the dictionary by inserting; then it might be best to try the private dictionary -> merge approach given in my second option.  Optimising this is highly dependent on the nature of the data etc and best to try both out to see what gives the best performance - there is no 'best fit'

Comment: Oh you could take a look at ReaderWriterLockSlim if there is simultaneous reads and writes going on and where the number of reads outweighs the number of writes; although from your question that doesn't seem to be the case.  I've used it, though, for in-memory caching and it's better than Monitor.Enter when the insert operation is complex enough

Comment: Golden rule (from Donald Knuth): "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". Just try a straightforward lock() statement first (use a private `new object()` as the sentinel) and see how it goes. If you're happy with the performance just stick with it :)

Comment: Andras Only problem is in the project that I'm working on it's not straight forward measure to see the impact of a change like this. That's why I'm asking if anyone knows the answer. Obviously for performance stuff you gotta go head and benchmark it and it's the only way to ensure.

Comment: @dr. evil - even though you've already accepted - am just preparing a little bit of guidance in response to your last comment.  It's a bit like a shot in the dark - but might offer some help...

Comment: Nice, I'm looking forward to it :)

Comment: @dr. evil - actually, I've spent 20 minutes trying to come up with a few simple rules but I can't; it's simply too woolly without knowing the exact processes involved (I ended up tripling the size of my answer and was only about half way through!)  Sorry!

Comment: :) No problem, I think we can still with just locking them until there is a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @dr. evil - I've tried again; kept it simple.  Check back in ten :)  (don't like leaving loose threads - sorry for the pun)

Answer (score 3):

Yup, this is the exception you can get when you insert an element just as the dictionary is busy increasing the number of buckets.  Triggered by another thread adding an item and the load factor got too high.  Dictionary is especially sensitive to that because the reorganization takes a while.  Good thing, makes your code crash quickly instead of only once a week.

Review *every* line of code that's used in a thread and check where a shared object is used.  You haven't yet found the once-a-week crashes.  Or worse, the ones that don't crash but just generate bad data once in a while.